# Install specific version of a plugin with install-plugin command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I cant see examples of how to do this:
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/

I backup a list of all plugins installed and their versions.

I want to use install-plugin command to install all plugins (and their specific versions) from the list.

I dont see option to specify version to install-plugin command

Answer (score 8):

To install a specific version you can run the command and pass a parameter with a colon like this:
`install-plugins.sh git:3.9.1`

or alternatively add the list of plugins to a file (`plugins.txt` for instance):

```
git:3.9.1
saml:1.0.7
```

and run it with the following command:
`install-plugins.sh plugins.txt`

For versions of Jenkins 2.357 an up, install-plugins.sh has been removed. The command should now be this:
`/bin/jenkins-plugin-cli -f /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt`

Comment: where is this script located? and where should we place this plugins.txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can download jar file from here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool

```
$ rm -rf /usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap*

$ ls /usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap*
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap*': No such file or directory

$ echo $JAVA_OPTS
-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false

$ java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.8.jar --plugins ldap:2.7
Done

$ ls /usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap*
/usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap.jpi

$ echo "http://<jenkins-url>/restart"
http://<jenkins-url>/restart

$ ls /usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap*
/usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap.jpi

/usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap:
META-INF  WEB-INF

$ cat /usr/share/jenkins/plugins/ldap/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: rsandell
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_211
Extension-Name: ldap
Specification-Title: The Jenkins Plugins Parent POM Project
Implementation-Title: ldap
Implementation-Version: 2.7
Group-Id: org.jenkins-ci.plugins
Short-Name: ldap
Long-Name: LDAP Plugin
Url: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ldap-plugin
Compatible-Since-Version: 1.16
Minimum-Java-Version: 1.8
Plugin-Version: 2.7
Hudson-Version: 2.277.1
Jenkins-Version: 2.277.1
Plugin-Dependencies: mailer:1.34
Plugin-Developers:
Plugin-License-Name: The MIT license
Plugin-License-Url: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
Plugin-ScmUrl: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ldap-plugin
```

[image]

[image]